# Composition of multiple functions onto one, each at a certain keyword

Tags: python, functional-programming, toolz

I have three functions:

```
def addition(a: int, b: int):
  return a + b

def increment(x: float) -> int:
  return int(x) + 1

def decrement(y: int) -> int:
  return x - 1
```

I would like to compose `increment` and `decrement` on top of `addition` to get a function which has the signature of new structure. Note that I don't want yet to run the resulting function (lazy composition).

How would I do such a thing when things like `toolz.compose` expect one input/output of the composed functions, and `functools.partial` or `toolz.curry` cannot get a function as a parameter (they treat it as if it were a value).

Essentially I'm looking for the higher order version of partial/curry.

EDIT:
I can't use a lambda because I want the new function to have the signature of `int` and `float`, and I want to be able to get this signature from the resulting function using `inspect.signature`.

So given functions a, b and c, and certain keywords k1 and k2, I'd like to connect a, b on top of c, on keywords k1 and k2, and get a function with signature of the params of a concatenated with the params of b.

If we stick to the example above, I want something like:

`new_func = pipeline(addition, via("a"), increment, via("b") decrement)`

where `via` composes a function onto an unbound keyword of the pipeline so far.

The result, `new_func`, would be a function that expects two variables, `x: float` and `y: int` and returns an `int`.

Comment: 1) You can assume all functions are pure and all arguments are non optional.
2) It's a bit limiting to have just unary functions, it feels like some simple syntactic sugar can solve this and this is what I'm after.

Comment: Is decrement supposed to be `x - 1`?

Comment: _"Essentialy I'm looking for the higher order version of partial/curry"_ - `partial` and `curry` _are_ higher-order functions - they take a function as input and return a function as output...

Comment: Using your three functions, please share an example composition expression and what you expect the output to be.

Comment: @user633183 please take a look.

Answer (score 0):

How about using a lambda function ?

```
ask_and_add = lambda : addition(get_input(),get_input())
```

You can then call it whenever you need it as such:

```
ask_and_add()
```

You'll get prompted for two consecutive inputs and you'll get the sum.

Comment: Right that will work but not in my case. I changed the question to reflect better what I meant.